# How to properly make a service telling systemd that it is set up?

Tags: python, services, dependencies

I have the following Dependency in a small IOT-Project:

MySqlServer < DeviceServer < Webserver

The DeviceServer cannot start without the MySqlServer being started and set up and the Web-Server cannot start without the Device Server.

I used `Requires, After` in the `.service`. But my Device-Server does not return a Code. The Device-Server never returns after being called.
I am wondering how to tell systemd that the DeviceServer is now set up and can be used by other services.

I guess, I could fork after the Setup is made and return as the father. Then the child would become adopted. However, then I could most lightly not use `service reload` etc.

So how to make the DeviceServer return a code and keep it running.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Would a simple `ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 60` for `webserver.servcie` do the job, i.e. just add some buffer time before the next service is executed?

Comment: If you don't know how the device server's status can be checked, you can't expect internet strangers to know it either.

Comment: Most lightly. This is a good workaround and if nothing else works, I will go with that.
However, I would like to make it run properly.

Comment: @berndbausch
I do not know how to tell it to systemd. How to make any service returning "anything" to systemd and keep running...
Someone could give an answer without knowing anything about my device-sever...
I am able to make the device-server running given there is a solution and given that I will learn this soultion...

Answer (score 1):

The usual answer here is to implement a `Type=notify` service using [`sd-notify`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_notify.html).  This means when you start a service it will remain in the `activating` state until the process "notifies" systemd that it is ready.  When that notification happens, the service enters the `active` state.

The `[Service]` section of your unit file should contain:

```
[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=webserver
```

Then add similar code to your webserver:

```
#include <systemd/sd-daemon.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
        /* Sleep to emulate 10s bootup time */
        /* Expect status 'activating (start)' during this */
        /* `systemctl start`, will block */
        sleep(10);

        /* Send a signal to say we've started */
        sd_notify(0, "READY=1");

        /* Units which are After= this unit will now start */
        /* `systemctl start` will unblock now */

        /* Sleep to emulate 10s run time */
        /* Expect status 'active (running)' during this */
        sleep(10);

        /* Send a signal to say we've started the shutdown procedure */
        sd_notify(0, "STOPPING=1");

        /* Sleep to emulate 10s shutdown */
        /* Expect status 'deactivating' during this */
        sleep(10);

        return 0;

        /* Expect status 'inactive (dead)' at this point */
}
```

This is far superior to a simple `ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 60` on dependent services because it triggers based on actual events.  If your service is ready earlier, your dependents will launch ASAP.  If it's not ready within 60s, your dependents will wait as long as necessary.

If you are not the developer of that application, you need to figure out how the application signals to the outside world that it's ready.  Perhaps it logs to a file, or perhaps you keep using wget on it until it returns something sensible.   In that case, you might want to make a watcher service that starts at the same time as your MySqlServer.  Then takes care of the notification based on whatever info is available to it.  In this case, DeviceServer would depend on your watching service instead of MySqlServer.